# Does Firebase charge for document writes that don't actually change any field values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to update app version on Firestore on a field named `appVersion` in a document named `userA`. I update `appVersion` to Firestore and don't care about remote `appVersion`.

Will Firebase charge me money if remote `appVersion` equals local `appVersion`? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I'm using Blaze plan which I have to pay $0.18/100K. Look like it small but for huge users that is not.

I have  a Firestore database like this.
[image]
I used this code in Android/Java to update appVersion:

```
String appVersion = "2.0.0";
App.getInstance().mFirestoreUsers
   .document("GgRu62z0b2CgQFbgNebe")
   .update("appVersion", appVersion)
   .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
      LogWrapper.i(TAG, "update appversion complete: " + appVersion);
 });
```

What i want to ask is, if user document on Firestore has appVersion value is "2.0.0" and i use above code to send the **same** value, will Firebase count up 1 write or 0?

Comment: It's not really clear to me the situation you're describing.

Comment: So you are actually asking if you are charged even if you update a property within a document with the exact same data, right? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, you're correct. Thanks to Doug for updating the title for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) documentation, the below are the free quota limits:

[image: Free Quotas]

Related to your question, yes, it will charge, since it's a new write to the database. It won't matter if you are just writing again the same value or a new one. Firestore won't check if the value is the same or not, it will charge per writing on the database.

In addition to that, I would recommend you to look at the documentation [See a Cloud Firestore pricing example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example), for you to check how it's charged and the pricing works on Firestore. Besides that, it provides some examples of how to calculate, for you to check it.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for your info. Actually i checked it but they don't said anything related to "write same data to Firestore". I also updated the question, can you check it? Thanks

Comment: Hi @TruongHieu thanks for updating the question! I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Since this is the first one answered my question so I will mark this as an answer what i need. Look like someone disappoint and give me -1. Thanks for your help anw!

Answer (score 3):

Because you are asking if you are charged even if you update a property within a document with the exact same data, the answer is **yes**. It doesn't really matter if you update a document with different data or with the exact same data, you'll always be charged with a write operation. An update with the same data, is basically considered an update too. So you'll be charged for that.

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer that was posted before and provides the same information. I believe adding new information  would be good, instead of just providing the same as another answer. :)

Comment: @gso_gabriel I asked the OP a question in the comment. So seeing that no answer was accepted, I provided my own answer. Thanks for doing things right.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank for your info. I believe that you an have same answer on this question. So I decided to make his answer as correct answer and giving you +1 for help. Thank you!